# Optimal division of functions between source files

Tags: c, multithreading, compilation, linker

My C program has two threads, both of which interact with two external interfaces. There's too much code for one source file, so I'm splitting it in two. What is the right split?

One thread, *MtoD*, takes a message off an IPC message queue, processes it, and then sends commands to the driver of a physical interface. The other thread, *DtoM*, receives interrupts from that driver, processes the input, and then posts the results in a message to an IPC queue.

The obvious ways to split the code in two are:

- **by thread**: two source files, MtoD.c and DtoM.c, each holding all the functions of a single thread - but both files will have to deal with both of the interfaces
- **by interface**: two source files, M.c and D.c, each doing all the business related to a certain external interface - but the threads run through both files.

My concerns are

1. **code maintenance**. Doing it by thread makes it easier to follow the logic of a thread (no switching between files). But someone who'd write this object-oriented would probably wrap the interface to the IPC queues in one class, which would be in one file, and the driver interface in another, in the other file.
2. **performance**. If you have object files M.o and D.o, each will have just one external library to deal with - but they have to call into each other during execution of a thread. Does that incur any overhead (if the linker has made them into one binary)? If you have MtoD.o and DtoM.o, you could declare most functions as `static`, which might enable some more compiler optimizations. But would they both need links with the external libraries?

Which way is optimal?

Comment: If performance matters, you may split your C files into more and #include all of them while keeping all the statics.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Good point, though that solution would sacrifice the advantage of recompiling only the object file whose underlying source code has changed.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting one and you probably get BOTH options being recommended, simply because both have advanteges and disadvantages and it much depends how one values these.

Ok, third option: one thread ? If I get you right you connect a interface to an IPC, so if one thread both reacts to input on either side and sends it out the other side ? I dont think you loose much responce time this way, if any and you have it all in one place. If source is too big you can look into which classes you may naturally separate rather than separating into threads or interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I'm primarily interested in the trade-offs between those advantages and disadvantages, which for me are a bit hard to gauge with my current knowledge. Not sure whether one thread would be able to listen on both sides - the message queue and the driver - so I think I'm probably a bit safer having separate threads listening to them.